# Estimating response of a filter given its order and roll off frequency

Tags: active-filter

As far as I know, for any filter we if we know that filter has 1kHz bandwidth we can infer that the 3dB point is at 1kHz. In some cases I only have the limited data for the filter. For example [this module](https://www.dataforth.com/catalog/pdf/scm5b30_31.pdf)'s filter is given as 1kHz. In an other document the filter is specified as 6-pole filter. But I cannot figure out whether the filter is Bessel or Butterworth or ect. I also noticed another manufacturer produces the same modules with same naming [here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/5B30_31.pdf). They look exactly the same but they both do not mention each other and different brand labeling on them.

So I have the knowledge of the filter that it is 6-pole and 120dB per Decade above 1kHz:
[image]
But I dont have the transfer function or the name of the name filter. In that case, how can I estimate the dB at lower frequencies? Can you give an example how can we estimate the dB at 100Hz and 500Hz for instance?

Comment: Bandwidth and 3 dB point are generally unrelated except in the specific case of low pass filters. You need to rethink your opening line.

Comment: *...filter has 1kHz bandwidth we can infer that the 3dB point is at 1kHz* That is not universally true, Linkwitz-Riley filters for example have their cutoff point at - 6 dB. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkwitz%E2%80%93Riley_filter  The -3 dB (or -6 dB) point is simply a **definition**. The definition can be different for different filters.

Comment: *...how can I estimate the dB at lower frequencies?* You mean: "How can I estimate the **attenuation** at lower frequencies?" You can't! There is not enough information given. We can only **assume** that the attenuation at 100 Hz and 500 Hz is less than 3 dB. I suggest that you read a book about filters (and filter design) to learn better how filters are specified.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Okay , I thought there might be a rough estimate. I guess the only way is to empirically obtain(with a network analyzer), thanks.

Comment: I also noticed the link to the other manufacturer was not working now I updated https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/5B30_31.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, knowing the -3dB and rate of rolloff above it may tell you nothing about the flatness of the filter below the -3dB point.

You need to know what type of filter you have. Three passband 'extremes' are the Bessel, the Butterworth, and the Chebychev response.

A Bessel filter is fairly predictable, as it gets higher order it gets closer to a Gaussian amplitude response.

A Butterworth filter is fairly predictable, as it gets higher order it gets closer to flat from DC to a substantial fraction of the passband.

With a Cheby, all bets are off, as the passband ripple is an important part of the design specification. Some applications may tolerate a 1dB ripple (or more) in exchange for a faster rolloff, some may specify 0.1dB ripple (or even less) for accuracy across the passband.

Comment: How about for 2kHz can we estimate the dB which is higher than 1kHz(3dB point)? Can we estimate the dB? It says 120dB per decade after 1kHz.

Comment: *Can we estimate the dB?* "The dB" means nothing, if you want to be taken seriously when talking about filters stop saying "The dB". Ask about the **attenuation**. "dB" is the unit, like Celcius or Kelvin. We ask for **temperature** and not "the Celcius" when we want to know how warm it is outside.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I meant to say "attenuation in dB". If per decade 120dB after 1kHz, I guess it means at 11kHz the attenuation will be 123dB, is that correct? Or nonsense? How about for 2kHz how can we estimate this?

Comment: The devices you link to are quite complex, I do not think they are designed to have a **predictable** frequency response. I think these devices are designed to be used at **mains frequency** so that means **50 or 60 Hz.** If you need a more accurate / predictable frequency response you will need to use something different. You simply cannot assume that this device behaves as if it is a "nice, well behaved filter" because it simply is not. The 1 kHz cutoff is very likely only there to prevent noise and spurs on the mains to disturb the measurement.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Here they have a series of them at different input outputs and cut offs:https://www.dataforth.com/catalog/pdf/DataforthCustomProductList.pdf For some instrumentation I need to use 1kHz as antialiasing(also high CMR and  isolation) similar to the one ending with 31-1092. I wanted to estimate the behavior of the filter at various frequencies.